# Replace text inside li tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<li ondblclick="editThisTag(this)" title="New Account0123" class="select2-selection__choice">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    Testing Text
</li>
```

I want to replace text inside `<li>` tag **"Testing Text"** on button click.
`<li>` tag have `<span>` tag and normal text as child. `<span>` tag should remain as it is and only need to change **"Testing Text"** text on button click using jQuery.

Comment: button would be outside li tag which i haven't mentioned but need to change text on html button click.

Comment: Are there multiple `li` elements? If so, how do you determine which `li` should be affected from the button click?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I can determine which `li` will be affected but i only need to change text of current `li` tag.

Comment: @SanketS but that's my point - *how* do you determine what the current `li` is? We need to see more of your code, both the HTML and your JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `span` inside the `li` then get the text node after to it and update the text

```js
$('#change').click(function() {
  $('li.select2-selection__choice')
    // get the span inside, and use `[0]` to get dom object
    .find('span')[0]
    // get next node after span, which is text node
    .nextSibling
    // update the text content with new value
    .textContent = 'text';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">Change Text</button>
<ul>
  <li ondblclick="editThisTag(this)" title="New Account0123" class="select2-selection__choice">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    Testing Text
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Or following method using **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** , **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** and **[`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**

```js
$('#change').click(function() {
  $('li.select2-selection__choice')
    // get all nodes including text node and comment node
    .contents()
    // filter to get only text node and which is not empty
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length;
    })
    // replace it with new text
    .replaceWith('text');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">Change Text</button>
<ul>
  <li ondblclick="editThisTag(this)" title="New Account0123" class="select2-selection__choice">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    Testing Text
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you describe what is use of `this.nodeType` and why you select it as 3?

Comment: @SanketS :  `textNode` have node value as `3`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Answer (score 2):

Having a function to find the text you want to change.

```
jQuery("li").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace("Testing Text", "hello world"); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o9va6mqe/

Working fiddle ^

Comment: this will remove the span

Comment: span tag should not be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose with the tag the text you want to change so you can specify which part of li will be change. Do it like this.

```js
$('button#changeText').click(function() {
  $('li.select2-selection__choice').find('font').html('HELLO WORLD');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="changeText">Change Text</button>
<li title="New Account0123" class="select2-selection__choice">
  <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
  <font>Testing Text</font>
</li>
```